# Why do call interceptors in Play! Framework contain parameterized Http.Context?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

While writing a controller interceptor using the `@With` annotation, I figured that the `call` method of the associated `Action` contains a parameterized `Http.Context`. Since we can always refer to the current `Http.Context` via the `Http.Context.current()` call (which is execution context safe as well), why does Play!'s `call()` method have that as the parameter? Just wondering...am I missing something here?